# XSLT special character Error

Tags: xslt

I am new too XSLT and I want to know how to get `<` and `>` node values returned by XML
to be represented by XSLT.

My code looks something like this.

```
      <A>
         <a1><=8</a1>
         <a2>>=7</a2>
      </A>
```

When I am trying to execute this with XSLT. I am getting an error 
Name cannot begin with the '8' character, hexadecimal value 0x38.

Please help me in solving this!!!

Comment: I want < and > values of the numericals as those are related to results.Any help is highly appreciated!!!

Comment: use &gt; and &lt; to get > and < characters

Comment: XML node values we are getting from a stored procedure dynamically.So where should I add this &gt; and &lt; My question may look silly but as I said I am new to this XSLT concept.

Comment: This will never work. Your xml is not well formed xml. `<` has to be "escaped" as `&lt;`, or the text content has to put into CDATA (`<![CDATA[<=8]]>` You have to change the  "*stored procedure*".

Comment: @hr_117 Your comment should be an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested as answer:

This will never work. Your xml is not well formed xml.
*The ampersand character (&) and the left angle bracket (<) must not appear in their literal form* (e.g. [xml syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#syntax))

`<` has to be "escaped" as `&lt;`, or the text content has to put into CDATA.

```
<![CDATA[<=8]]>
```

You have to change the "stored procedure"

Comment: disable-output-escaping="yes" is not working so without changing procedure cant we do that?

Comment: There is not possible "trick" in xslt to load an "wrong" (**not well formed**) xml.